# In App Purchase in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, in-app-purchase

Is there any official **In App Purchase for windows phone** same like iPhone (which connects to iTunes).

Here is the nice explanation about **In App Purchase**

> In-app purchase (IAP) means buying more content for the app through
>   Marketplace while in the app.  Another name often used for them is
>   micro-transactions for the smaller purchases.  Buying a new costume
>   for your character.  You need several thousand gold coins to get that
>   pet cat in the game you are playing.  You could play the game and
>   grind away killing monsters over several hours and earn the XP to get
>   the cat, or you could pay $2 now via in-app purchase and have the cat
>   straight away.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no such possibilities at the moment on the Windows Phone 7 platform. Also the next version of WP7 OS codename Mango will not have the In-App purchase feature. Here is the comment from Todd Brix

> @BNID, @Justin Pitta; In app commerce has been on the short list of
>   features we’d like to enable, but unfortunately it did not make the
>   cut for Mango.

[AppHub changes in Mango](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/07/20/windows-phone-developers-get-new-app-hub-features-mango-app-submission-just-one-month-away.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I saw that other applications are doing this by redirecting to the website where you can execute the purchase

Answer (score 4):

There's this service called [MoVend](https://www.movend.com/) which supposedly supports in-app purchases on Windows Phone. Haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 2):

Being added to WP8:
http://www.slashgear.com/in-app-purchases-featured-in-windows-phone-8-20234914/

Answer (score 0):

Try CarrotPay. It is absolutely a micro-payment service for micro-transaction. Very competitive charge scheme for penny transactions. They already released mobile payment API. [Check it out on their website](http://www.carrot.org)