# Does Windows Phone marketplace allow in-app purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-phone-7.1

It it possible to allow a user of a Windows Phone application to buy media content from within an application? For example to implement a music sales store inside of an application, with the ability to save music right to the media library on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also [windows phone ApplicationPolicy for in app payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209545/windows-phone-applicationpolicy-for-in-app-payment)

Under certain conditions In-App Purchase is permitted but no facility to do so is currently included in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that the platform has support for in-app purchases. Refer to this SO question for more information: [In App Purchase in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006429/in-app-purchase-in-windows-phone)

The ability of saving to the media library appears to be supported, however, so a 3rd party in-app purchase product could provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The thread you have mentioned offers MoVend as an example of a 3rd party solution. I doubt that MoVend is even a 3rd party application. It seems like it just provides API's to PayPal and some other payment processors. So I guess this means that all I need is to integrate with an online payment system from within the app, and I am ready to sell music from within the app. I wonder what MS app certification authorities think of it.

Comment: I've seen some apps that allow paypal operation: see emross war in the windows marketplace

Answer (score 1):

They will be supported in windows phone 8
http://www.slashgear.com/in-app-purchases-featured-in-windows-phone-8-20234914/

Comment: I really hope that's one of those things they backport to Windows Phone 7.8!